# Convert Dynamic SQL to Static SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, stored-procedures

Can any one help me from solving this `Dynamic query` to a `Static one`

```
DECLARE @REPCD VARCHAR(10)
SET @REPCD='CA%'

IF (CHARINDEX('*',@REPCD,1)>0 OR  CHARINDEX('%',@REPCD,1)>0) 
BEGIN
    SET @WHERE = ' AND REP_CD like ''' + REPLACE(@REPCD, '''', '') + ''''
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @WHERE = ' AND REP_CD = ''' + REPLACE(@REPCD, '''', '') + ''''
END
```

I would like to convert the above query to something like this

```
SELECT * FROM REP
WHERE CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('%',@REPCD,1)>0 THEN REP_CD like 'CA%' END AS REP_CD
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why won't this work?

```
...
WHERE REP_CD LIKE REPLACE(@REPCD, '*', '%');
```

In the case where `@REPCD` contains no wildcards, `LIKE` works just like `=`. So there is no reason for a `CASE` or any other variation of conditional logic at all.

There currently is no way to make `LIKE`/`=` interchangeable without dynamic SQL. Well, I guess there is this convoluted way (assuming REP_CD can't be NULL), but I don't have any clue why this is better than what I posted above.

```
SET @REPCD = REPLACE(@REPCD, '*', '%');

...
WHERE REP_CD LIKE CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('%', @REPCD) > 0 THEN @REPCD ELSE REP_CD END
AND REP_CD = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('%', @REPCD) > 0 THEN REP_CD ELSE @REPCD END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from Rep
where Rep_CD like replace(@repcd, '*','%')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DECLARE @REPCD VARCHAR(10)
SET @REPCD='CA'
set @REPCD=REPLACE(@REPCD,'*','%')
SELECT * FROM REP where REP_CD like @REPCD
```